# Why are the bars of my p:chart overlapping

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jqplot

Developing a Java8 application with jsf and primefaces, I encountered a small issue with the bar of my barChart which are overlapping. So my question is: How can I configure the width of the chart without impacting the interval of the axis?

My first idea was to modify the axis with `xAxis.setTickInterval();` but the problem is that my axis is a DateAxis in month/year and it showed multiple times the same month in the axis (not multiple time the bar (cf the screenshot) reducing the overlapping).

[image]

And the code:

```js
private void createChart() {
  globalGradeEvolution = new BarChartModel();
  globalGradeEvolution.setTitle("Evaluation globale");
  globalGradeEvolution.setLegendPosition("e");
  
  //Define two axis
  Axis yAxis = globalGradeEvolution.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
  DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis("Dates");
  
  //cacteristics of x axis
  xAxis.setTickAngle(-30);
  xAxis.setMax(LocalDate.now().getYear()+"-"+LocalDate.now().getMonthValue()+"-"+"15"); // middle of the month
  xAxis.setTickFormat("%m/%Y"); // example: 08/2018
  
  //cacteristics of y axis
  yAxis.setLabel("Notes");
  yAxis.setMin(min);
  yAxis.setMax(10);
  yAxis.setTickFormat("%.1f");

  globalGradeEvolution.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
 }
```

```html
<h:form>
    <p:chart type="bar" model="#{statChartView.globalGradeEvolution}" style="height:400px" responsive="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: some invisible custom css? or related to responsiveness? Or related to unvisible PF version? Or...

Comment: I have tried without my custom CSS and I have also tried in the navigator to see which css property is affecting the width but I did not find the solution here. Without responsiveness the result is the same. It may come from the PF version (which is 6.2)

Comment: Have you tried it with just the Showcase implementing your bare example and does the same behavior happen?

Comment: @Melloware when I use two chart series on the same barChart it does work. However when I use only one chart series it makes the same result as before. As a matter of fact it does also for a two chart series, the cause comes from the dateAxis ! When I remove it everything is great
Edit: this is an opened issue referenced here github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3684

Comment: @Fabien I updated the answer below to show its an existing bug for people coming here in the future.  You may also want to comment on that GitHub bug that you are having the issue as well!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in PrimeFaces + JqPlot combination.

The bug has been reported to PrimeFaces here:  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3684